# Automatic clenaup of Posix Semaphores, System V alternative

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, systemd, sysv-ipc

According to my research, there is a automatic cleanup mechanism on /dev/shm directory, made by systemd, with removeipc configuration.

1. Will systemd remove my posix semaphores (under /dev/shm) at runtime of my application even if I don't unlink them according to its removeipc feature ?
2. I don't want to change the systemd settings. So the systemV semaphore is a good alternative for me? I don't see but is there a automatic cleanup stuff on sysV ipc objects? Or should I continue with Posix semaphores?

Comment: According to the [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) documentation, System V semaphores are also cleaned up.

Comment: @IanAbbott So changing the systemd settings is only solution right ?

Comment: Your question is off topic here. From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.